# Alternate Python List Reverse Solution Needed

Tags: python, list, reverse

I had a job interview today. During it I was asked to write down an algorithm that will reverse a list. First I offered the answer using the reversed() method:

```
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = reversed(x)
    for i in y:
        print i
```

The senior developer conducting the interview asked me if I know another way, upon which I wrote down the other known method with slicing:

```
   x = [1,2,3,4,5]
   y = x[::-1]
```

Unfortunately he was unhappy with this solution as well and asked me to think of another one. After few minutes I said I could not come up with a better one. He said that this was not good enough for their standards.

I am perfectly fine with his opinion and have no problem practicing more on my code. My question is, what is a better solution that I am not aware of, if there is one. Could there be some other more 'programmer' way...Only other thing that comes to mind is recursion, however I thought of it only after the interview was already done. 
Thanks.

Comment: I suppose he was looking for you to suggest an algorithm, rather than pre-made (and correct!) Python methods.

Comment: Did you ask him what he was looking for?

Comment: it seems that was the case, I wasn't thinking outside the box. It was my first interview for this kind of position. I was too nervous and thinking how stupid I was instead of asking him to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Both your answers are good in terms of python so the interviewer must have been asking you to implement your own method:

Using recursion:

```
def recur_rev(l):
    return recur_rev(l[1:]) + l[:1] if l else l
```

Or a list comp and range starting at the length of l -1 and going in reverse:

```
l = list(range(100))

print([l[ind] for ind in range(len(l)-1,-1,-1)])
```

Using itertools.count:

```
from itertools import count
cn = count(len(l) -1, -1)

print([l[next(cn)] for ele in l])
```

For efficiency use a generator expression:

```
rev  = (l[next(cn)] for ele in l)

for ele in rev:
    print(ele)
```

Or using map:

```
print(list(map(l.__getitem__,range(len(l)-1,-1,-1)))) # list needed for python3

[99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

without the list call on map we will get a map object we can iterate over in python3, you can use [itertools.imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) in python2 to achieve a similar result

Comment: interesting answer. Thank you. I guess I was thinking of giving the most pythonic answer instead trying to invent a solution of my own.

Comment: @user44772, like I said in terms of python your answers are fine especially using reversed in terms of efficiency so the only real logical explanation is the interviewer wanted you to come up with alternative non builtin methods

Comment: The first 2 are different approaches. The others are entertaining to look at but pretty much the same, i think the only other different approaches are swapping list items or popping them off

Answer (score 4):

I guess your interviewer wanted to hear something like this:

A straightforward way to revert a list is to find out its length, then iterate from len-1 downto 0 and append the i-th element to the result. This approach works fine with real lists, but how can we revert a generator, i.e. something whose length is not known and cannot be found? (Good pythonistas use generators and yields instead of lists and returns).

Here's where we need a data structure known as "stack". A stack is like, well, a stack of things, like plates, put on the top of each other.

[image]

Whatever you put *last* comes out *first*, whatever was put *first* comes out *last*. So, our strategy will be like this:

- while there are items, put each item onto the stack
- while the stack is not empty, pop items off the stack and return them

Stacks can be programmed in python using lists, where `.append` puts an item on the top of the stack, and `.pop` removes the last thing off the stack:

```
def reverse(it):
    stack = []
    for item in it:
        stack.append(item)
    while stack:
        yield stack.pop()
```

Of course, Python already has a built-in stack, and it's the stack of *call frames*. We can use that instead of the simulated one above, which leads us to the following *recursive* solution:

```
def reverse(it):
    head = next(it)
    for item in reverse(it):
        yield item
    yield head
```

in python3, this is even more elegant:

```
def reverse(it):
    head = next(it)
    yield from reverse(it)
    yield head
```

Again, this works with arbitrary iterables, whose length is unknown at the call time.

Answer (score 2):

One simple algorithm that could be easily ported to other languages would be:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = []
for i in len(x):
  y.append(x[len(x) - 1 - i])
```

Or using an iterator. This could be easily ported to be used with a chained list where you don't know the length:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = []
x_iterator = iter(x)
try:
  while (1):
    y.insert(0, x_iterator.next())
except:
  print y
```

Or a more pythonic version with insert:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = []
for elem in x:
  y.insert(0, elem)
```

Comment: yeah, list comprehension, but I replaced the example, it was bad.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your interviewer didn't want you to use built-in Python methods, but an algorithm that's more language-agnostic. Something like:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst2 = []

while len(lst) > 0:
    lst2.append(lst.pop())
```

or

```
lst2 = [lst.pop() for _ in lst[:]]
```

Comment: It is very possible that he wanted something like this, however I was slightly nervous at that given moment and it also felt unusual to code on a piece of paper without online help. However its a good lesson for some future interviews. Thanks Adam.

Comment: `while len(lst) > 0` can be replaced by `while lst`

Answer (score 2):

How about something like that:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in xrange(len(x) / 2):
    x[i], x[-i - 1] = x[-i - 1], x[i]

print(x)
```

The idea is to swap array elements from opposite directions

Comment: I love the xrange(). That would make the interviewer ask next on range() vs xrange().

Answer (score 1):

I like this way:

```
def reverse(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr) / 2): 
        arr[-i-1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[-i-1]
```

Basically iterating through the first half of the array and swapping `i` and `len(i)-i-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(text):
  rev = []
  for let in range(len(text),0,-1):
    rev.append(text[let-1])
  return ''.join(rev)
```